# Batch normalization (restoring saved models)

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow

In TensorFlow we  use `update_ops=tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.UPDATE_OPS)` to keep track of exponential moving averages.

If I save a model and restore it later, are those saved moving averages still available? How do I restore the previous averages to continue training my restored model?

Comment: Please take a look at this [issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/3460) and let me know if it helps.